# How to retrieve different types of DNS records in Rust?

Tags: dns, rust

I need to send a DNS request to check the A, AAAA, MX and SOA records of a domain.

There're 2 popular DNS libraries: [trust-dns](https://crates.io/crates/trust-dns) and [dns-parser](https://crates.io/crates/dns-parser). Neither of them has an example. trust-dns doesn't support what I need to do and dns-parser's documentation doesn't help.

Comment: I think SO is not the better place to ask this. You should open an issue in github to ask for explanation and maybe for more examples in the documentation.

Comment: @Boiethios the question, on the surface, seems on topic: how to retrieve the DNS records. The OP showing that they have found some libraries and at least looked for examples and at the documentation shows that they have tried a little bit.

Comment: @Shepmaster I said "not the better place": I think this question is on topic, but IMO OP has more chances to get answer in the github project.

Comment: @Boiethios oh, definitely, the OP should raise an issue on trust-dns' issue tracker. I don't think that dns-parser is appropriate is it's just about parsing the DNS response, no actual network requests.

Comment: FYI, I've updated the docs on TRust-DNS and the TRust-DNS Resolver libraries with many more examples. https://docs.rs/trust-dns/0.11.0/trust_dns/ and https://docs.rs/trust-dns-resolver/0.3.0/trust_dns_resolver/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [domain](https://crates.io/crates/domain) crate appears to support your usecases. It also is built on top of futures which is nice for the needed network requests.

```
extern crate domain;
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio_core;

use std::str::FromStr;
use domain::bits::{DNameBuf, ParsedDName};
use domain::iana::{Class, Rtype};
use domain::rdata::{A, Aaaa, Mx, Soa};
use domain::resolv::Resolver;
use futures::Future;
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;

fn main() {
    let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
    let resolv = Resolver::new(&core.handle());

    let name = DNameBuf::from_str("www.rust-lang.org.").unwrap();

    let v4 = resolv.clone().query((name.clone(), Rtype::A, Class::In));
    let v6 = resolv.clone().query((name.clone(), Rtype::Aaaa, Class::In));
    let mx = resolv.clone().query((name.clone(), Rtype::Mx, Class::In));
    let soa = resolv.query((name, Rtype::Soa, Class::In));

    let addrs = v4.join4(v6, mx, soa);

    let (v4, v6, mx, soa) = core.run(addrs).unwrap();

    println!("-- A --");

    for record in v4.answer().unwrap().limit_to::<A>() {
        println!("{}", record.unwrap());
    }

    println!("-- AAAA --");

    for record in v6.answer().unwrap().limit_to::<Aaaa>() {
        println!("{}", record.unwrap());
    }

    println!("-- MX --");

    for record in mx.answer().unwrap().limit_to::<Mx<ParsedDName>>() {
        println!("{}", record.unwrap());
    }

    println!("-- SOA --");

    for record in soa.answer().unwrap().limit_to::<Soa<ParsedDName>>() {
        println!("{}", record.unwrap());
    }
}
```

I've never seen this crate before today, so I don't know that I'm using it correctly or efficiently, but it does seem to work.